# ITenantIdentificationStrategy not called when manually resolving in ASP.NET Core 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, autofac, asp.net-core-5.0

I am upgrading Autofac from 4.9.4 to 6.0.0 and after making the necessary changes I've come across an issue where I am manually resolving a tenant service like so:

```
///_serviceProivder is System.IServiceProvider
module = _serviceProvider.GetService(moduleType.Type);
```

In 4.9.4, using `GetService()` triggered a call to my `ITenantIdentificationStrategy`, but in 6.0.0, it no longer calls it. I am using ASP.NET Core 5 (upgraded from ASP.NET Core 3.1). The `ITenantIdentificationStrategy` is being called in other areas so it appears to be registered correctly in the `ConfigureContainer` method, just not when manually resolving types.

Is there a new way to manually register tenant services so that I can run the identification strategy?

Comment: Have you tried upgrading Autofac while leaving ASP.NET on 3.1? Just want to check if the change is Autofac or ASP.NET.

Comment: Was unable to revert back my project, so I made a new minimal ASP.NET CORE 3.1 project with Autofac multi-tenant packages. Autofac (4.9.4), Autofac.AspNetCore.Multitenant (2.0.1), Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInject (5.0.1) and the ITenantIdentificationStrategy is fired on IServiceProvider.GetService() call. When I then upgrade autofac to Autofac (6), Autofac.AspNetCore.Multitenant (4.01) and Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection (7.1.0), then then ITenantIdentificationStrategy is NOT fired after calling GetService().

Comment: In this sample ASP.NET Core 3.1 project, I changed the Autofac version to 5.2.0 and it too, does not fire ITenantIdentificationStrategy from GetService()

Comment: I've added a note [to the pull request for .NET 5 support](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac.AspNetCore.Multitenant/pull/28) that we should test this scenario and verify it's working (or fix it if it's not).

Comment: In general you can check out [this repository and branch](https://github.com/alsami/Autofac.AspNetCore.Multitenant/tree/feat/net5_support) and execute the sandbox project for .NET 5. There it is just working fine, it might be that the explicit support is required for it to work, which has not been merged yet.

Comment: @alsami thanks for pointing me to that repository. I downloaded it and modified it so that the ValuesController is injected with IServiceProvider and then in the Get() method, I do a manual resolution like "var service = _serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(ITestService));". Right after this line, the tenant ITenantIdentificationStrategy is not called. Also, I did note in a previous comment that I tried in an Asp.net 3.1 project instead of 5 as mentioned in the original question. I believe its not related to dotnet 5 but rather the difference between Autofac 4.x to 5.x

Comment: In this case this is per design and probably around since we started supporting ASP.NET Core 3.1, if not even longer. You can inject `MultitenantContainer` now and call resolve on that one instead. Currently there is still an extension `GetAutofacMultitenantRoot` which may be called on `IServiceProvider`. It will be deprecated with the next major release as well so you are better off with directly injecting `MultitenantContainer`. Keep in mind that when hitting a controller, there has already been a tenant-identification and a specific scope may have been set.

Comment: @alsami thank you! I got it working using MultitenantContainer. It did require an autofac dependency in a separate project where the manual resolution was happening. Not a big deal but I did like hiding behind the IServiceProvider interface. Any plans to support this in the future?

Comment: We weren't able to keep hiding behind the interface of `IServiceProvider` with the changes that came with ASP.NET Core 3. I'd suggest to use an Adapter if you want to manually access multi-tenant container. That way you can hide the details from whatever class is consuming it. The other way is to cast `IServiceProvider` to `AutofacServiceProvider` and then the same with `ILifetimeScope` in it but that would not be a good choice IMO.